# Making a camera with a green tint

Tags: texturing, game-engine, camera, light

[image]
I'm trying to make a horror game with a green tint to the camera (like above)
Is there any way to make this?

Comment: I think this should be done by post production,
increasing the contrast and converting the RGB into a monochrome green color and adding a hard vignette,
Some one may help you in programming but i dont know how to program that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible:

You have to use **GLSL**, make your horror scene, dont use any lights (for the scene).
After, you may parent a Spot to your camera (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> make parent, keep transform), and set the color of the spot to a green tint, decrase the energy for a better effect. There is many parameters for the spot, you just have to try ;)

[image: Green tint]

Comment: I used a Spotlight, but it only seems to make the objects green.

Comment: Are you in Texture mode?

Comment: I'm not. Should I?

Comment: You must be in texture mode. See my screenshot. To set texture mode, click on the menu right to "Object Mode", and select "Texture".

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using post production,I dont know how to program that but I can tell you how to make it using the compositor and you program it or some one edit that answer and give you the script.
here I have this image from "outlast" with normal vision.
[image: normal vision]

After applying a node tree like this:

[image: Node tree]

Here is the result:
[image: The result]

Comment: can you illustrate with an image that is not as disturbing?

Comment: Sorry,but it is from the same game he point at and I wanted to give the best demonstration.